# Javascript most efficient way to combine array elements with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I'm trying to combine arrays of string with unique combinations, like 'Mark|Tom' but without 'Tom|Mark'

I have written this code:

```js
let arr = ['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark']
let sets = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let others = arr.filter(name => name != arr[i])
  others.forEach((other) => {

    let newel = arr[i] + '|' + other
    let test = newel.split('|')
    if (sets.includes(test[1] + '|' + test[0]) || sets.includes(newel)) return

    sets.push(newel)
  })

}

console.log(sets)
```

This is iterating through every array element and then creating another array of other elements from basic array and then iterating through them (again iteration), creating a combination, checking if there is reversed combination of our elements (if this was created in previous loops) and if there is no such combination = push it to target array.

Is there more elegant way to do that task?

Comment: can you  post what is desired output ? also why it should be `Mark|Tom` not `Tom|Mark` ?

Comment: just run code snippet
It's irrelevant if it's Mark|Tom or Tom|Mark, it has to be unique combination

Comment: Output your code showing is doesn't matches with logic, so it will be better to desired result, You want to `Tony|Dany|Mark` also to be in output ?

Comment: Sure! The next step is to match treble combination

Comment: please update your post with desired result

Answer (score 3):

what about this one:

```js
const arr = ['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark'];
const sets = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    sets.push(arr[i] + '|' + arr[j]);
  }
}

console.log(sets);
```

Also you can make `arr` unique before start the calculate:

```
const arr = [...new Set(['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark', 'Tom'])]; // ['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark']
```

Comment: You can create a running snippet on SO mate, [`how to create a running snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @CodeManiac Ahhh thank you very much! I was looking for it :)

Comment: Always welcome, anyways good answer and probably the most efficient one +1

Answer (score 2):

I would make your array a set so it will remove all duplicates initially like so:

```
new Set(['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark']);
```

Now, you can pair the `ith` element with all elements up to the `nth` element using `.flatMap` and `.reduce` like so:

```js
const name_arr = Array.from(new Set(['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark']));
const res = name_arr.flatMap(
  (name, i) => name_arr.slice(i+1).reduce((a, n) => [...a, name+'|'+n],[])
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Set of passed array, loop through the array, for each index get the array after that index and loop thorough this other array and build combinations

```js
let arr = ['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark']

const uniqueCombo = (arr) => {
  let newSet = [...new Set(arr)]
  return newSet.reduce((op, inp, index) => {
    newSet.slice(index + 1,).forEach(v => {
      op.push(inp + '|' + v)
    })
    return op
  },[])
}

console.log(uniqueCombo(arr))
console.log(uniqueCombo(['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D']))
console.log(uniqueCombo(['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This approach filters out the index which has been previously used to push item to array.

```js
const arr = ['Tom', 'Danny', 'Mark'];

const comb = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    comb.push(arr[i] + '|' + arr[j]);
  }
}
console.log(comb);
```